# Can't select .NET Framework 4.6.1 in Visual Studio Project properties

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6.1

I installed .NET Framework 4.6.1 using this url: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49981

But when I open a Visual Studio (2015) Project I can't select version 4.6.1

See image:

[image]

Why I can't choose 4.6.1 which I installed?

Comment: Do you have update 2 of visual studio installed?

Comment: What kinde of project and did this project was created earlier with earlier version (ex. 4.5) ?

Comment: Then install update 2, .NET 4.6.1 is only available since update 1.

Comment: Marcin Project was created with 4.6.1 But I can't open the project using .NET 4.6.1 (even it is installed)

@DeMama ok, thanks, it's installing right now. I'll keep this topic updated

Comment: the link to the .NET Framework 4.6.1 Targeting Pack now changed to the following link
https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting

Answer (score 16, accepted):

go to <s>http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html</s> https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting

download and istall `.NET Framework 4.6.1 Targeting Pack`

[image]

I'll then recommend using an extension called `Target Framework Migrator`
you can download it from here https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47bded90-80d8-42af-bc35-4736fdd8cd13
or get it through tools->extension and updates

Note that if you change the target framework to 4.6.1 using the dropdown in Visual Studio you may experience VS to hang for like a minute or so where using the `Target Framework Migrator` avoids this problem and you can upgrade all the projects in the solution at once.

Also 4.6.1 comes preinstalled with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

Update : Make sure to install Developer Pack after .NET Framework installation as depicted in below image.

[image]